# Specify the id in Object ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to delete the a from the database but specifying an ID is a bit of a problem to me.

I render the data from data like this:

```
renderUsersTable(users) {
    return (
      <table className='table table-striped' aria-labelledby="tabelLabel">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Action</th> 
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {users.map(items => 
        <tr key=""> 
        <td>{items.id}</td>
        <td>{items.name}</td>
        <td>{items.age}</td> 
        <td>  
            <button type="button" onClick={this.deleteItem} className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>  
        </td>
        <td>  
            <button type="button" onClick={this.editItem} className="btn btn-success">Edit</button>  
        </td>
         </tr> 

         )} 
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
```

and I want to delete the selected user from the database the same way I was picking them from it:

```
deleteItem(users){
    users.map(items => 
    axios.delete('https://localhost:5001/inventory/' + items.id));
  }
```

but I get an "TypeError: users.map is not a function".

data:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Some Item",
        "age": 22
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Some Item",
        "age": 22
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Some Item",
        "age": 22
    }
]
```

Comment: It means that users is probably not an iterable. Standard debugging procedure is to `console.log(users)` in the deleteItem function. Also you function name is deleteItem, but should it not be called deleteItem**s**?

Comment: users is not an array, please check

Comment: it is an array "this.state = { users: [], loading: true };"

Comment: How are you passing the user object to the component? Are you passing it to another component as props? If so, is that component a class based or functional component? What does the console.log say users is

Comment: @Michelangelo I want to delete just ONE item out of the LIST.

Comment: also, once you have your map issue fixed you need to set your tr key="" to tr key={items.id}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to delete a specific item from your list, you should adjust your code to not iterate over the list of items, but provide an argument in your function for the specific ID you're trying to delete.

```
deleteItem(itemId){ 
  axios.delete('https://localhost:5001/inventory/' + itemId).then(() => {
    this.setState({items: this.state.items.filter(x => x.id != itemId)})
  });
}
```

and you should change your render function to look for the item.id for each function relative to the single item that is being mapped

```
{users.map(item => 
    <tr key={item.id}> 
        <td>{item.id}</td>
        <td>{item.name}</td>
        <td>{item.age}</td> 
        <td>  
            <button type="button" onClick={() => this.deleteItem(item.id)} className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>  
        </td>
        <td>  
            <button type="button" onClick={() => this.editItem(item.id)} className="btn btn-success">Edit</button>  
        </td>
    </tr>
)}
```

Comment: This is actually what I wanted but it still doesn't work. Now it deletes all of my JSON objects instead of just only one. Is there any other way to specify an id?

Comment: Make sure all of the objects in your array have different IDs.  I was assuming they were all unique.  If they aren't then you're going to have to use a different property that is unique to the specific item you are trying to delete

Comment: I edited my answer so that the UI should update to remove the element from react state if your server returns a successful message for deleting the item.